# Lowering/Disabling touchpad acceleration in GNOME 40 (Wayland)

Tags: fedora, touchpad, wayland, libinput

I have set the touchpad speed slider to ~50% in Mouse & Touchpad Settings. I find this good enough most of the time but if I move my finger a bit too fast, the pointer flies to the edge/corner. If I set the touchpad speed too low, the small movements require multiple swipes.

I want to lower the acceleration to match it with the "precision touchpad" of Windows, which is perfect (or disable acceleration if acceleration can't be lowered).

`$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices` gives the following result:

```
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=06cb Product=cd41 Version=0100
N: Name="SYNA7DB5:01 06CB:CD41 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-SYNA7DB5:01
S: Sysfs=/devices/platform/AMDI0010:01/i2c-0/i2c-SYNA7DB5:01/0018:06CB:CD41.0001/input/input10
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse1 event7 
B: PROP=5
B: EV=1b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=2e0800000000003
B: MSC=20
```

From `# libinput list-devices`:

```
Device:           SYNA7DB5:01 06CB:CD41 Touchpad
Kernel:           /dev/input/event7
Group:            8
Seat:             seat0, default
Size:             103x75mm
Capabilities:     pointer gesture
Tap-to-click:     disabled
Tap-and-drag:     enabled
Tap drag lock:    disabled
Left-handed:      disabled
Nat.scrolling:    disabled
Middle emulation: disabled
Calibration:      n/a
Scroll methods:   *two-finger edge 
Click methods:    *button-areas clickfinger 
Disable-w-typing: enabled
Accel profiles:   flat *adaptive
Rotation:         n/a
```

I tried `# libinput "AccelProfile" "flat"` but it tells me `libinput: libinput-AccelProfile is not installed`. I did `# dnf search libinput` and installed all the packages:

```
libinput.x86_64 : Input device library
libinput-devel.x86_64 : Development files for libinput
libinput-test.x86_64 : libinput integration test suite
libinput-utils.x86_64 : Utilities and tools for debugging libinput
xorg-x11-drv-libinput.x86_64 : Xorg X11 libinput input driver
xorg-x11-drv-libinput-devel.x86_64 : Xorg X11 libinput input driver development
                                   : package.
```

but the result stays the same.

---

OS Name: Fedora 34 (Workstation Edition) 
OS Type: 64-bit 
GNOME Version: 40.0.0 
Windowing System: Wayland

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you've already done so, but you can download `gnome-tweaks` and set the pointer acceleration there, through the GUI. If that doesn't work, please let me know and, if it doesn't, I'll see if I can help you with an alternative way to adjust it.

**EDIT:** I tried searching the settings using the CLI but to no avail. `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.mouse` has `accel-profile` which can be adjusted; unfortunately, `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad` only gives the following options: `click-method`, `disable-while-typing`, `edge-scrolling-enabled`, `left-handed`, `middle-click-emulation`, `natural-scroll`, `send-events`, `speed`, `tap-and-drag`, `tap-and-drag-lock`, `tap-button-map`, `tap-to-click`, `two-finger-scrolling-enabled`. So it looks like you're out of luck.

Another thing worth mentioning is that for Wayland, there is no `libinput` configuration file. The configurable options depend on the desktop environment's support for them. It is, however, odd that changing the option in `gnome-tweaks` does not yield the expected result, as that works on my laptop. My guess is that there is something not working properly/hardware support issues with your particular model of touchpad.

The only thing I could recommend trying is to install `dconf-editor` to see if that allows you to adjust it using the GUI.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention - there is no option for the touchpad acceleration (profile) in ```gnome-tweaks```. I have set the mouse acceleration profile to flat, but that doesn't affect the touchpad acceleration.

Comment: Please check the edit.

Comment: The only thing related to the touchpad speed in ```dconf-editor``` is ```/org/gnome/desktop/peripherals/touchpad/speed```, which doesn't offer anything more than the vanilla Settings GUI/CLI. At the current level of acceleration, it is unusable.

Comment: @user1029387 libinput handles touchpad acceleration slightly differently, see https://wayland.freedesktop.org/libinput/doc/latest/pointer-acceleration.html#pointer-acceleration-on-touchpads